# How to immediately update summary value, when column value in antd Table changes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I want to display a "simple" table, where rows are dynamically added. The records have a property `harn` and `amount`. Both are used to display a total amount using the formula `harn * amount / 100`.

This is my column definition:

```
const columns = [
  {
    //omitted;
  },
  {
    title: "Amount",
    dataIndex: "amount",
    render: (text, record, index) => {
        return (
            <InputNumber
                defaultValue={record.amount}
                min={0}
                formatter={value => `${value}g`}
                parser={value => value?.replace('g', '') || 0}
                onChange={e => {
                   record.amount = e
                }}
            />
        )
    }
  }
```

With the summary definition:

```
const summary = (data: readonly TableFoodType[]) => {
    let totalHarn: number = 0
    data.forEach(({ harn, amount }) => {
        totalHarn += harn * (amount / 100)
    })
    return (
        <Table.Summary.Row>
            <Table.Summary.Cell index={0}><span>Total: </span></Table.Summary.Cell>
            <Table.Summary.Cell index={1}>
                {totalHarn}
            </Table.Summary.Cell>
        </Table.Summary.Row>
    )
}
```

My goal is to update the summary, whenever a user updates the amount input in the cell, without explicitly saving, but I am at a loss on how to write the changed value from the `InputNumber` directly back into the record. As it stands right now, the summary is not being updated.

The documentation for an editable cell (https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell) looks hideously complex for a seemingly simple task like that, so I am wondering, if there was an easy way, that I am not seeing right now.

The whole compoenent is not designed to persist data, so all I am about right now, is to alter and display it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does seem excessively complicated.  Your component can store `data` in state and call `setData` from the `onChange` function of the `InputNumber`.

The Ant Design demo code is using some `Form` components around the input for the purpose of validation.  They also have additional state in order to control which component is currently being edited.  In this simple version, the whole "Amount" column is rendered as editable inputs and the changes are posted to the component state immediately.

The most annoying part is that the `onChange` function recieves a value that could be `number`, `string`, or `null`.  I am casting strings to numbers and ignoring null values.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);
```

```
const columns = [
...
    title: "Amount",
    dataIndex: "amount",
    render: (text, record, index) => {
        return (
            <InputNumber
                defaultValue={record.amount}
                min={0}
                formatter={value => `${value}g`}
                parser={value => value?.replace('g', '') || 0}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  if (newValue) {
                    const number =
                      typeof newValue === "string"
                        ? parseFloat(newValue)
                        : newValue;
                    setData(
                      data.map((row, i) =>
                        i === index ? { ...record, amount: number } : row
                      )
                    );
                  }
            />
        )
    }
]
```

As these changes are immediately reflected in `data`, you should not have to change anything in your summary.

Comment: ah, I was missing the setData hook, of course. Instead I was trying to update the record, hoping it would bubble up into the useState hook. Now it clicked. Terrific work - thank you :)